# Livy How to copy widget

Tags: python, kivy

How can i copy a widget in kivy?
But i don't want use copy module.
that module cannot edit width or pos etc...

```
#I don't want use this cause can't edit width or pos...
from copy import copy
copy()
```

Comment: what do you mean by copy a widget ?

Comment: Example.
There is A widget in Bclass but i want to show in Class too with something animation.
So i have to copy Widget from Class and show on Class.
He said my mind.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090620/can-i-copy-attributes-from-one-widget-to-another-in-kivy

Comment: In fact, I want to make like a iOS Blur.
something like this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwIRVxVITEw

he using mask and blur, but don't know how.
So i decieded make my way.

And first step, copy AWidget from Bclass.
Second, paste Widget on CClass and effect blur.
Third, synchronize scroll amount